# Go template - syntax for range

Tags: go, go-templates

In Go template, I have a map setup like this:

```
{{$key}}map := make(map[string]interface{})
```

And I want to iterate through the map using this:

```
{{ range $mapKey, $mapValue := {{$key}}map}}
```

And I am getting this error:

```
unexpected "{" in range
```

Looks like it does not allow nested {{}} inside another {{}}.  Is there anyway I can solve this issue ???

Answer (score 3):

You cannot generate variable names to be used in templates using the template engine itself. You seem to be in need of having multiple maps, one for each `$key`. So, use a map of maps:

```
m := make(map[string]map[string]interface{})
```

where `m[key]` gives the map for the key.

Then you can do:

```
{{ range $mapKey, $mapValue := (index $.m $.key)}}
...
{{end}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will keep this in mind. I looked at my code again and actually I dont have to do that.